# Redirects not working on Apache: htm to process as php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm converting over 500 pages from htm processing to php due to existing page redesign to php.
The easiest way to do this and avoid 500 redirects is simply to have the htm files processed as php in the .htaccess file, and put a 301 in the code.

I'm trying to do this with only the .htaccess file because if I put in a custom mime type it will be overwritten during a server upgrade, which would be catastrophic. I've tried everything for two full days, including just redirecting to a php file of the same name - no redirects work. I really just want to have htm processed as php.

It's the latest Apache server, and next to last version of php. The .htaccess file is in the ISO-8859-1 character set. The server does read the .htaccess file. It just doesn't do what I want.

I've tried all of the following in the .htaccess file and nothing works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test_htm_php.htm$ test_htm_php.php
//RewriteRule ^(.+)\.htm$ $1.php [L]
//RewriteRule "!\." "-" [H=application/x-httpd-php]
//RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s(.+)\.php [NC]
//RewriteRule ^ %1.htm [R=301,L]
//RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ [H=application/x-httpd-php]
//RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.htm$ $1.php
//RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.php [NC,L]
//RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ /$1.php [L,NC]

//RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s(.+)\.php [NC]
//RewriteRule ^ %1.htm [R=301,L]
//RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

Anyone have any ideas?
You can try these URLs:
https://visualwriter.com/test/test_htm_php.htm  - doesn't process as php or display
https://visualwriter.com/test/test_htm_php.php - doesn't display

Comment: The 500 error on your site is probably due to the `//` characters you are using in your file. To comment out a line use `#` char.

Comment: Thanks Amil. I think this is going to resolve the problem. I'm getting too rusty at writing too many types of code. :)

Comment: I corrected the .htaccess file so it works. Confirmed mod_rewrite is working. Confirmed rewrite will send an htm request to a php page of the same name. Set a mime handler in .htaccess for processing htm as php. Specified a php version (73) - no help. 

Still can't get any htm pages to process as php pages with any common code for doing that. .
RewriteEngine On
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .htm

Comment: How is PHP embedded into the web server - the module version, one of the fast cgi handlers, …?

Comment: maybe this helps `RewriteRule \.htm$ - [H=application/x-httpd-php5]` .

Comment: Thanks everyone. After 3-4 days of work, I updated first to PHP 7.4, which may have had something to do with it. 
"RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.php [L]" works. Now all I have to do is figure out how to add a 301 to that rule. 
This also works: AddType application/x-httpd-alt-php74___lsphp .php7 .php5 .php4 .php .php3 .php2 .phtml .htm